# Is matrix $H$ positive definite in TRPO algorithm?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, policy-gradient

TRPO Taylor expands the objective and constraint to

$$
\theta=\mathop{\arg\max}_\theta g^T(\theta-\theta_{\text{old}})\quad\text{s.t.}\quad \frac{1}{2}(\theta-\theta_{\text{old}})^TH(\theta-\theta_{\text{old}})\le\delta
$$

where $H$ is the Hessian matrix of KL divergence. The above is solved by the KKT conditions and the conjugate gradient method.

However, to use the conjugate gradient method, $H$ should be positive definite. So I wonder whether $H$ can be proved to be positive definite w.r.t. policy parameter $\theta$. It seems to be difficult because there is a neural network between $\theta$ and probability distribution.

If we cannot show that $H$ is positive definite, how can we use CG?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hessian of the KL divergence is equal to the Fisher matrix under certain regularity conditions. The Fisher matrix is the covariance of the [score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Score_(statistics)), therefore it's at least positive semi-definite.

Comment: You confirmed that the matrix is positive semi definite which was already known. OP is asking how can we guarantee it's positive definite. Not sure why he accepted the answer anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I believe H is positive semi-definite, CG here is used to get an approximate solution not the exact solution as mentioned in the paper, for example CG is used in inexact newton methods (both line search and trust region), when a non-positive curvature is detected, the algo simply stop CG iteration and generate some form of approximate solution.

However note that in paper Kakade, Sham M. "A natural policy gradient." Advances in neural information processing systems 14 (2001). The author states that "The Fisher information matrix of this distribution... and it is clearly positive definite" in Eq2, do not know the reason still.

Comment: Hi, welcome to CV. Please add the reference of the paper you cite in case the link dies in the future. Thx

Comment: Hi, in this way?

Comment: More in this way: `Kakade, Sham M. "A natural policy gradient." Advances in neural information processing systems 14 (2001).`

Comment: Ok, edited it. Thank you for informing.